# Excel VBA - UDF using Hyperlinks.Add to update ScreenTip -- Getting 2015 error

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a multi tab spreadsheet with one tab holding a table of data and I am using a UDF to use that to alter the colour of shapes based on there names across multiple sheets.  The UDF iterates through the sheets and the shapes on the sheets and updates the colour etc fine.

I then wanted to add a ScreenTip and I tested this in a following SUB and it works great in that it will add ScreenTips for all the shapes.

```
Sub Test2()

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    For Each shp In sht.Shapes

        sht.Hyperlinks.Add shp, "", "", _
        ScreenTip:="Hello2 from " & shp.Name
    Next shp
Next sht
  
End Sub
```

The issue comes to when I move this to the UDF and even after I strip out all the other formatting I am  doing and just leave the Hyperlinks.Add command I get a err2015.

```
Function ColourShape(theValue As String, ShapeName As String, ShapeVisible As Integer, DisplayText As String)
On Error GoTo FuncFail:

'Iterate through worksheets in active workbook
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
 
    'Iterate through shapes in each worksheet
    For Each shp In sht.Shapes
        'Check if shape Name is the one we are looking for
 
       
       'Add the Tooltop
    sht.Hyperlinks.Add shp, "", "", _
    ScreenTip:="Hellonnnn!!!!! from " & shp.Name
    
    Next shp
Next sht

ColourShape = ""
Exit Function
FuncFail:
ColourShape = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

So any help would be appreciated I am sure its a newbie error I am making.

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: Your code works fine! The difference from procedure ``Test2`` and the function ``ColourShape`` is that added some error handling and arguments to the function and none of the arguments are being used at this time! How are you calling the function?

Comment: I had striped out all the other parts of the code so i just had the bit that was failing.  I was calling the function from a cell as a UDF.